# html-testRunner not generate any report

Tags: python

So i install the module via this `command`:

```
pip check html-testRunner
```

And when i check for errors using `pip check html-testRunner`command:

```
No broken requirements found
```

My tests class:

```
import HtmlTestRunner

class Tests(BaseTests):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test_print_entries(self):
        # All the steps...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/dan/Downloads/nms/reports'))
```

**BaseTest**

```
class BaseTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Some stuff

    def tearDown(self):
        # Some stuff
```

The directory `C:/Users/dan/Downloads/nms/reports` exist

And run the test using this `command`:

```
python -m unittest C:\Users\dan\Downloads\nms\src\tests\tests.py
```

The test pass but i cannot ses at the end the message `Generating HTML reports...`
And my reports directory empty.

I am using `html-testRunner==1.2.1` and `python 3.8.1`

Comment: I don't know the unittest framework, but I wonder how/why your `Tests` class is getting picked up.  It isn't referenced anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean picked up ? test test starts and ended and works fine

Comment: Did you know the reason ?